# Not able to start Klov Server for extent reports from a jar file

Tags: java, spring-boot, automation, extentreports

I try to install klov-0.2.5.jar locally, my settings are as below:

1. Mongodb 3.2 running and listening on port 27017
2. klov application.properties file reside in the same folder as klov-0.2.5.jar
3. Have tried different ports for Klov (80, 90, 2571,1100), but all giving the same error as in description
4. Have tried it on mongoDB 5.0 with same result
5. Running it on windows 10, with application.properties settings as below:

> ```
> # klov
> application.name=Klov
> server.host=localhost
> server.port=1100
>
> # data.mongodb
> spring.data.mongodb.host=localhost
> spring.data.mongodb.port=27017
> spring.data.mongodb.database=klov
>
> # data.rest
> spring.data.rest.basePath=/rest
> spring.data.rest.default-page-size=6
>
> # redis, session
> spring.autoconfigure.exclude=org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.session.SessionAutoConfiguration
> spring.data.redis.repositories.enabled=false
> spring.data.elasticsearch.repositories.enabled=false
> spring.data.jpa.repositories.enabled=false
> org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext.enabled=false
> # use.redis.session.store=false
> # spring.redis.host=localhost
> # spring.redis.port=6379
> # spring.redis.ssl=false
> # spring.redis.database=0
> # spring.session.store-type=redis
> # server.session.timeout=-1
>
> # users
> server.admin.name=klovadmin
> server.admin.key=$2a$10$I/5TFi6BrHChUghTZEZfCO82txzu8L5brcK0CxhS3m.V6glfj2vZe
>
> # storage
> file.storage.location=./upload/reports/
>
> # schedulers
> scheduler.jobs.enabled=false
> # automatically delete older builds
> # default is -1 (keep all)
> # this count must be greater than 0 for this scheduler to work
> # scheduled to run daily at 12:00AM
> scheduler.job.builds.retain.count=-1
>
> # mail
> #spring.mail.host=
> #spring.mail.port=
> #spring.mail.username=
> #spring.mail.password=
> #spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.ssl.enable=true
> #spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.starttls.enable=true
> #spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.starttls.required=true
> #spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.auth=true
> #spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.connectiontimeout=5000
> #spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.timeout=5000
> #spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.writetimeout=5000
> spring.mail.test-connection=false
> ```

Once i try to execute jar file in my powershell i get:
[poerwshell outcome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CiupF.png)

> PS D:\klov\0.2.5> java -jar .\klov-0.2.5.jar
>
> .   ____          _            __ _ _  /\ / ***'* __ _ *(*)* __  __
> _ \ \ \ \ ( ( )_*_ | '_ | '*| | '* / *` | \ \ \ \  \/  __*)| |*)| | | | | || (*| |  ) ) ) )   '  |****| .__|*| |*|*| |*_*, | / / / /
> =========|*|==============|***/=/*/*/*/  :: Spring Boot ::        (v2.0.4.RELEASE)
>
> 2022-07-13 14:34:42.138  INFO 2796 --- [           main]
> com.aventstack.klov.Application          : Starting Application v0.2.5
> on fedoruk with PID 2796 (D:\klov\0.2.5\klov-0.2.5.jar started by
> mfedoruk in D:\klov\0.2.5) 2022-07-13 14:34:42.141  INFO 2796 --- [
> main] com.aventstack.klov.Application          : No active profile
> set, falling back to default profiles: default 2022-07-13 14:34:42.215
> INFO 2796 --- [           main]
> ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Refreshing
> org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext@7a3d45bd:
> startup date [Wed Jul 13 14:34:42 CEST 2022]; root of context
> hierarchy 2022-07-13 14:34:42.984  INFO 2796 --- [           main]
> .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Multiple Spring Data
> modules found, entering strict repository configuration mode!
> 2022-07-13 14:34:43.356 ERROR 2796 --- [           main]
> o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed
>
> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot load configuration class:
> com.aventstack.klov.Application
> at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.enhanceConfigurationClasses(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:414)
> ~[spring-context-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.8.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanFactory(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:254)
> ~[spring-context-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.8.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:282)
> ~[spring-context-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.8.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:126)
> ~[spring-context-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.8.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:694)
> ~[spring-context-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.8.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:532)
> ~[spring-context-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.8.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:140)
> ~[spring-boot-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.4.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:762)
> ~[spring-boot-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.4.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:398)
> ~[spring-boot-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.4.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:330)
> ~[spring-boot-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.4.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1258)
> ~[spring-boot-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.4.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1246)
> ~[spring-boot-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.4.RELEASE]
> at com.aventstack.klov.Application.main(Application.java:61) ~[classes!/:0.2.5]
> at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104)
> ~[na:na]
> at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:577) ~[na:na]
> at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:48)
> ~[klov-0.2.5.jar:0.2.5]
> at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:87)
> ~[klov-0.2.5.jar:0.2.5]
> at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:50)
> ~[klov-0.2.5.jar:0.2.5]
> at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:51)
> ~[klov-0.2.5.jar:0.2.5] Caused by:
> java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError: null
> at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer.newEnhancer(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:122)
> ~[spring-context-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.8.RELEASE]

Answer (score 0):

I dealt with it by:

- running the newest ver of klov in docker container
- then I copied the klov.jar file from container to my local path
- same properties, mongoDB 5.0.9
- typed java -jar -klov.jar
  all started with no issues